# MySQL: selecting rows which are followed by specific rows

Tags: php, mysql, select

How to select `id` of events which has value 105 only in case when there are two following and connecting events which has value 110 with all having same `category` from the sample table below?

By connecting events with value 110 I mean case when there is no other event (like 106, or 112) between 110 event's with same category.

```
 id     category    event
  8     100         110
 12     100         105
 19     101         112
 22     100         106
 31     100         110
 42     101         106
 121    100         110
 254    100         104
```

In the above example id 12 would be returned as it is prior 105 event to rows 31 and 121 which are connecting 110 event, by not having any other events between them, and all are in same category 100.

It's not that important how efficient the query is, or how many queries should be combined, as long it works.

UPDATE:
Simple way to express the question: return all 105s for which exist at least two later adjacent 110s in same category

Comment: I don't see why row id 22 doesn't brake your "connecting" thing.

Comment: row id 22 doesn't break the "connecting" thing as its not between 31 and 121 which are both 110 events in same category and those are "connecting" as there are no other events between those which would be in same category. I'm sorry if I confused you and I'm glad to have feedback how to describe this problem in more meaningful way

Comment: So simply: return all 105s for which exist at least two later adjacent 110s. Yes?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Yes, you are right two later adjacent 110s which are in same category. Thanks for correcting my question

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Just to clarify, query should result only those 105s that has the adjacent 110s _before_ any other 105. So if there are 105, 112, 105, 110, 110 only the later 105 should be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit clumsy in MySQL for the lack of analytic functions LAG and LEAD.

```
select distinct e105.id
from events e105
join
(
  -- all 110 that are directly followed by  a110
  select just_before.id, just_before.category
  from
  (
    -- all 110 and their direct predecessor
    select events.id, min(before.id) as just_before_id
    from events
    left join events before on before.category = events.category and before.id < events.id
    where events.event = 110
    group by events.id
  ) event110
  join events just_before on just_before.id = event110.just_before_id and just_before.event = 110
) e110 on e110.category = e105.category and e110.id > e105.id
where events.event = 105
and not exists
(
  -- a later occuring 105 still bevor the 110 pair
  select *
  from events bad105
  where bad105.category = e105.category and bad105.id > e105.id and bad105.id < e110.id
);
```

EDIT 1: I just notice, you may need DISTINCT for the case 105 - 110 - 110 - 112 - 110 - 110. Two 110 pairs would result in the same 105 found twice. I've added DISTICT above for that reason. I also added the qualifier e105 for the ID to be selected, for it was missing.

EDIT 2: I also notice you don't need NOT EXISTS, to get only the latest 105. As you already have all 105 candidates, all you need is an aggregation:

```
select distinct max(e105.id)
from events e105
join
(
  -- all 110 that are directly followed by  a110
  select just_before.id, just_before.category
  from
  (
    -- all 110 and their direct predecessor
    select events.id, min(before.id) as just_before_id
    from events
    left join events before on before.category = events.category and before.id < events.id
    where events.event = 110
    group by events.id
  ) event110
  join events just_before on just_before.id = event110.just_before_id and just_before.event = 110
) e110 on e110.category = e105.category and e110.id > e105.id
where events.event = 105
group by e110.id;
```

Comment: Does this apply to "query should result only those 105s that has the adjacent 110s before any other 105. So if there are 105, 112, 105, 110, 110 only the later 105 should be returned"?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I oversaw that. It's just one additional NOT EXISTS though. I'll add that.

Comment: thanks for your support. I'm looking forward for the updated solution

Comment: Thanks, I will test this and come back later.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want rows where the `event` is 105 and two rows with a larger `id` have `event` equal to 110.  If so:

```
select t.*
from sample t
where t.event = 105 and
      (select count(*)
       from sample t2
       where t2.category = t.category and
             t2.id > t.category and
             t2.category = 110
      ) = 2;
```

EDIT:

I think you can do what you want with `group_concat()`:

```
select t.category
from sample t
group by t.category
where concat('|', group_concat(event order by id separator '||'), '"') like '%|105|%|110|110|%)
```

You can then join back to get the details where event is 105.

Comment: Yes, I would want rows that have larger id and event equal to 110. However, there must not be any other events between those 110 which seems to be missing from your solution if I read it correctly

Comment: Thanks, I will test this and come back later.